# Type error for initial empty object with useState (union type)

Tags: typescript, use-state

How can I set the types correctly for an initial empty object + an interface?

```
interface IInputs {
  prop1: string
  prop2: string
  prop3: string
}

const [inputs, setInputs] = useState<IInputs | {}>({})
```

Gives the following error in the value attribute of the input:

```
Property 'prop1' does not exist on type '{} | IInputs'.
  Property 'prop1' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Partial` to make all properties optional.

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState<Partial<IInput>>({})
```